# Avoid dupliacte entries in MySQL table with auto suggestions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, duplicates

I'm working on a system, where authenticated users can suggest ideas, what to do next...

To be more precise, users can suggest activites, which are then entered into the MySQL database. Then, all users can see those activites and can vote for the ones, they like the most.

The problem is: I always have to think about the laziest users, that just enter something new, without checking, if this entry (or something similar) already exists...

The point is: say its about gaming, then in the end, I might have

- Zelda
- Zelda: Breath of the Wild
- Zelda Breath of the Wild
- Zelda BOTW
- Zelda: BOTW

and propably 5 other alternatives, that I forgot about.

And no, I can't just compare it to a game library and insert the full names, as games would only be 10% of the hole list. Topics are from every category, so you can't compare it to databases, as I'd say...

What I thought about is: On keydown (when users are entering a new topic), the database is searched for entries and theres something showing saying "did you mean xxxx" and users would be able to click on it to vote for the already existing entry, rather then creating a new one with a more or less similar name.

Even with that way, users COULD still enter new entries though. Of course, I could prevent them from creating the EXACT SAME entry again, but not, if it's a variation.

Anybody has an idea, on how to prevent them from submitting the varieties, rather then taking/voting for an already existing entry?

Again, comparing to a database won't work most propably, as it can be everything from lifestyle, gaming, programming, etc....

Comment: Use full-text search to check if there's something similar before inserting.

Comment: Use common synonyms for your tags and search by them too. Otherwise use system like stackoverflow where only users with certain reputation can create new tags.

Comment: @Barmar how would you do that for the MySQL database? You mean just something like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry LIKE %enteredText%"?

Comment: That's a simplified form, but I suggested using full-text search using the `MATCH` operator.

Comment: `LIKE` will only work if the new input is an exact substring of something already in the table, it won't look for similar words. But realistically, this is a difficult problem, you would really want natural language processing.

Comment: @Barmar do you have any docs for MATCH operator? Couldn't find anything really.. also, how could I go for natural language processing?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Hmm.. what I'm thinking now, if it might be easier and more efficient to do the comparison with jQuery.. so just getting all activities in an array and then comparing it from the frontend side in jQuery.. any ideas on how to do that, except for an exact match with substr?